# Determining 32-bit Mask in C

Tags: c, 32-bit, bitmask

I'm not a C programmer, but found myself in a situation where I need to do some coding. I am using an ADC to determine voltage levels running through a device, and the ADC has 3 channels (0, 1, 2). I need to be able to determine the voltages on each channel separately. I found a function that allows me to set a channel for scanning, but it requires a mask. I have no idea how this works. Below is the documentation:

> // Sets the channel mask void ADC_SetChanMask(uint32 mask) {...}
>
> Parameter mask sets the channel that will be scanned. Setting bits for
> channels that do not exist will have no effect. For example, if only 6
> channels were enabled, setting a mask of 0x0103 would only enable the
> last two channels (0 and 1).
>
> Example: If the component is setup to sequence through 8 channels, a
> mask of 0x000F would enable channels 0, 1, 2, and 3.

In my code, I need to enable channels 0, 1, and 2 separately, but never combined. If I could get some help understanding how this works, that would be amazing!

Comment: mask = 1 for channel 0, 2 for channel 1, and 4 for channel 2.

Comment: 0x0001, 0x0002, and 0x004

Correct?

Comment: Could you create an answer explaining how they got to the mask of 0x0103 for combining channels? I would like to accept your answer to give you the credit you deserve.

Comment: @FoxDonut or just 1, 2 and 4. You don't have to write them in hex if you don't want to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

channel 0, 1, 2, 3 ... correspond to the masks `1 << channel` which are 1, 2, 4, 8 ...  You can make a mask of multiple channels by combining bits with the `|` (bitwise OR) operator.

The example mask 0x0103 corresponds to channels 0, 1 and 8.  Since only 6 channels are enabled the high order bit is ignored.

Comment: Thanks again - I appreciate your quick response.